# Understanding Iteratee in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

Here is an example from the Reactive Web Apps in Play book:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.libs.oauth.{OAuthCalculator, RequestToken, ConsumerKey}
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.mvc._


import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

class Application extends Controller {

  val loggingIteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] {
    array => Logger.info(array.map(_.toChar).mkString)
  }

  def tweets = Action.async {
    val credentials: Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = for {
      apiKey <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiKey")
      apiSecret <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiSecret")
      token <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.token")
      tokenSecret <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.tokenSecret")
    } yield (
      ConsumerKey(apiKey, apiSecret),
      RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)
      )
    credentials.map {
      case (consumerKey, requestToken) => WS.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json")
          .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
          .withQueryString("track" -> "cat")
          .get {
            response =>
              Logger.info("Status: " + response.status)
              loggingIteratee
          }
          .map(response => Ok("Stream closed"))
    } getOrElse {
      Future {
        InternalServerError("Twitter credentials missing")
      }
    }
  }

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

I am having a hard time understanding the dangling line:

```
loggingIteratee
```

In this case it seems to log posts about cat from twitter. But how does it achieve that? We didn't pass anything to it.

Comment: it seems like `get` method needs a function from response to `Iteratee` and then it uses it internally. See docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequestHolder `get[A](consumer: (WSResponseHeaders) ⇒ Iteratee[Array[Byte], A])`

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that a minute ago. Thanks! Could you please write an answer? I will be happy to accept! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` method needs a function from response to `Iteratee` and then it uses it internally. See docs:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSRequestHolder

and source code (here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala)

```
/**
 * performs a get
 * @param consumer that's handling the response
 */
def get[A](consumer: WSResponseHeaders => Iteratee[Array[Byte], A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]] = {
  getStream().flatMap {
    case (response, enumerator) =>
      enumerator(consumer(response))
  }
}
```

so it basically puts each response through this `Iteratee`